# Add cell address to dynamic array in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, loops, recursion, sudoku

I have a script wherein I loop through a 9x9 array and if a cell contains a 0, it will change the number such that the number is unique across the row, column and a 3x3 square within. Every time one such cell is found and changed, I want to add that cell location to an array so that if it comes to be that the number that replaced the 0 is not optimal, I can easily go back to that cell that was changed and try a new number. How do I do this?

Below is the code I have written so far and I have denoted my "pseudo-code" with three apostrophes (''')
that further explains what I want it to do.

The Check Function determines whether a number from 1 to 9 can be placed in the current cell based on the conditions I mentioned (Sudoku Rules).

It deals with recursion so let me know if I need to explain in a more clear manner.

```
Sub Solve()

Dim x As Integer, y As Integer, row As Integer, col As Integer, rw As Integer, cl As Integer, a As Worksheet, puzzle As Range, n As Integer, num As Integer
Dim startcol As Integer, startrow As Integer, check1 As Boolean, check2 As Boolean, check3 As Boolean, r As Integer, c As Integer, x1 As Double, y1 As Double, z As Boolean
Dim fillednums(1 To 9, 1 To 9) As String

Set a = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Puzzle")
Set puzzle = a.Range(Cells(4, 4), Cells(12, 12))


startcol = 4
startrow = 4

For row = startrow To startrow + 8
    For col = startcol To startcol + 8
        If a.Cells(row, col).Value = 0 Then
            For num = 1 To 9
                If Check(col, row, num) = True Then
                a.Cells(row, col).Value = num
                    '''Add cell address to array
                Call Solve
                ElseIf num = 9 And a.Cells(row, col).Value = 0 Then
                    '''Go back one index of the array (fillednums) and use check() function for numbers greater than the one in the cell and up to 9
                    '''If that still doesnt work, go back to cell before this one that was changed and check again (recursively)
                    '''Call Solve() again to try new number
                'a.Cells(row, col).Value = 0
                End If
            Next num
        End If
    Next col
Next row
            
            
End Sub
```

Comment: In recursion, you need to pass the current board to the next level. Here, you're trying use a single excel grid for all levels, which will be difficult at best (if not impossible). You will need to keep the board state in memory then pass the updated state to the next level: `Call Solve(CurrentBoard)`  where a single change will be made then the new board will be passed to a deeper level. This continues until the board is correct or an update fails in which case it goes back up a level to try a different number\position.

Comment: I gave it more thought...you can use the single grid to hold all levels for this.

Comment: Like the way I suggested?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the recursion, you can start with the first empty cell in the puzzle. For each possible value, pass the next free cell to the child to check for a solution. The process continues until a solution is found (assuming valid puzzle).

The main Solve function must return True or False so the parent knows if a solution has been found.

```
Function GetNextCell(cc)  ' get next free cell in puzzle
   GetNextCell = Cells(cc.Row, cc.Column+1) ' move next column
   If (GetNextCell.Column = 13) Then  ' go to next row
      GetNextCell = Cells(cc.Row+1, 4)
   End If
   If GetNextCell.Row = 13 Then ' off the grid
      GetNextCell = Nothing  ' no more cells
   End If
   If GetNextCell <> Nothing And GetNextCell.Value <> "" Then
      GetNextCell GetNextCell(GetNextCell) ' skip filled cells
   End If    

Function Solve(cc) as Boolean    
    ' we only care about our single cell
    For num = 1 to 9 ' all possible values for this cell
        cc.Value = num
        If Check(cc.column, cc.row, num) Then  ' so far so good
            NextCell = GetNextCell(cc)  ' get next cell for child to process
            if NextCell = Nothing Then  ' no more cells and current values work
                    Solve = True  ' puzzle solved
                    Exit Function
            Else  ' call child with next cell
                If Solve(NextCell) Then  ' did child solve puzzle ?
                    Solve = True  ' puzzle solved
                    Exit Function
                End If
                ' Child could not find solution based on current values
            End If
        End If
    Next
    
  cc.Value = ""    ' No solution found at this point, must revert back to parent to try next value
  Solve = False  ' no solution found    
End Function

Solve(GetNextCell(Cells(4,3)))  ' first empty cell in block, must return true
```